How can I keep each objects gradient transition co ordinates when joining all?
I have a color gradient on multiple objects origin so colors mix in the middle but when I join them the origin sets gradient to new mass object which makes sense but I need it to remain centered on each panel. First screen shot is what I need it to look like after joining, 2nd screenshot is what actually happens when all is joined. 3rd screen is my shader node set up.



